# Is it possible SET 'status' at other row false when NEW.status = true?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, database-trigger

I have an AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER, that i want only one row that has `status` is TRUE. Here is my trigger,

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_true AFTER UPDATE ON table1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (NEW.status = 1) THEN
UPDATE table1 SET status = 0 WHERE id <> NEW.id;
END IF;
END
```

I try change `status` from 1 to 0 there is no error. But when I try change from 0 to 1 there is error like this,

```
Can't update table 'table1' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger
```

Thanks in advance, sorry for my bad language.

Comment: You cannot alter another records in the trigger in the table which's event fires the trigger. If you do not obtain error message when you "try change status from 1 to 0" then either the table is empty or none record matches the condition or all records matched have already zero value (nevertheless it is very strange - in theory the error message must be obtained in any case).

Answer (score 0):

A trigger cannot action the table it was fired upon, so what you want to do cannot be achieved with a trigger.

Another option would be to re-formulate your `update` queries so it updates all needed records at once, like:

```
update mytable
set status = case when id = :myid then :status else 0 end
where id = :myid or (status = 1 and :status = 1)
```

Here, `:id` and `:status` represent the query parameters.

The `where` clause selects records that match the `:id` parameter - if the new status is `1`, it also selects existing records whose status is `1` (there should be only one).

Then, the `set` clause uses a `case` expression to update the status of the new record and reset the previous one (if any)

Answer (score 0):

First, in MySQL 8+, you can have MySQL enforce the uniqueness.

```
alter table table1 add column status_true varchar(255) generated always as
    (case when status then status end);

create unique index unq_table1_status_true on (status_true);
```

Now, the database ensures uniqueness.

You can update the value using a single `update`:

```
update table1
    set status = not status
    where status or id = 2
```

The "4" is the id you want to change to be the active one.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b25681373d2a646d6a65f6e84a4664d8) is a db<>fiddle.